# IIS 7.5 How to configure custom 401 Authentication Error Page with Basic Authentication

Tags: iis-7.5, http-basic-authentication, custom-errors

I have a website running under IIS 7.5. I am using Basic Authentication. I want to set it up so that if authentication fails it redirects them to a www url. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have tried setting a 302 redirect to the URL however that isn't working, it still displays the 401.1 or 401.2 error pages

Comment: Ok, I got it so that it re-directs to a URL however it doesn't prompt for authentication, it just assumes authentication has failed and straight away redirects...